# Write mpfr objects to file in R

Tags: r, file, output, mpfr

I have a variable, which contains mpfr object.

```
> currentPrice <- mpfr(as.character(reduceData[1, 2]))
> currentPrice
1 'mpfr' number of precision  97   bits 
[1] 14.22857142857142857142857143301
```

How can I write this value to text file without cutting it and tranforming to short version like this:

```
> as.numeric(currentPrice)
[1] 14.22857
```

Thank you for your attention.

Command dput outputs this:

```
> dput(currentPrice)
new("mpfr"
    , .Data = list(<S4 object of class structure("mpfr1", package = "Rmpfr")>)
)
```

Comment: `sink( filename.txt );`  `cat(as.numeric(currentPrice));`  `sink();`

Comment: @Sathish No, man. Your solution writes short value(**14.22857**) to file, but I need long version(**14.22857142857142857142857143301**)

Comment: @Sathish type of variable - list, class - mpfr

Comment: I don't understand. Explain again, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using print method called `print.mpfr` in `Rmpfr` package

```
library( 'Rmpfr' )
currentPrice <- mpfr( '14.22857142857142857142857143301', precBits = 260 )

sink( 'filename.txt' )
print(currentPrice, digits = 260)
sink();
```

**Output in your file.**

```
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  260   bits 
# [1] 14.2285714285714285714285714330100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000037941082567172255283680561956483693602320305788044194384954889318036909905910031240694550294963195196244918820116425935087779567863032980333526378302622106275521218776702880859375
```

Comment: How to print only value without additional information?

Comment: I do not know how to suppress the header. May be you can post process that file by removing headers.